# Since nature highly favors the pyranose forme of Ribose, what explains the fact we find it in the form of furanose in DNA and RNA?

Tags: dna, rna, carbohydrates

I read in my notes that relative abundance of ribopyranose represents about 80% of all ribose in solution (including the alpha and beta anomeres).

I'm curious as to why evolution favored the use of the least abundant conformation for DNA and RNA.

Do we have enzymes that convert pyranose to furanose in order to achieve this? or are we just using the furanose?

Thank you,

Pierre-Eric

Comment: Because the ribose in RNA is a component of a nucleotide and is not a molecule unto itself. It has the 5' phosphates and 1' nitrogenous bases attached, and those functional groups will alter the conformation of the ribose in the nucleotide.

Comment: But then, my question should be read like this:

Is the cell using ribofuranose or ribopyranose  in the synthesis of nucleosides?

and if it is the latter, how.... or when is it converted?


or even... does the cell synthesize nucleosides at all? Or do we simply use the one we get from digestion of food?

If we do get it all from digestion, then wherever the nucleosides are formed in the foodchain, wether it is in bacterias or protozoas... 

How does it go from pyranose to furanose (if the pyranose are used), and why are the furanose used and not the pyranose if it is the other way around?

Comment: Look at your textbook for the De Novo Purine Nucleotide synthesis. You do not start with ribose you start with 5-Phosphoribosyl-1-pyrophosphate and its precursor is ribose 5-phosphate. The 1,3-diaxial interactions of a C5 phosphate group likely pushes the molecule into favoring the furanose form as the negativity of the phosphate and the lone pairs on the ring oxygen are likely not very happy that next to each other to assume the pyranose conformation.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the reference that says that pyranose structure is more abundant? That may be true but I am not too sure about it.